# Ignore hyphens when sorting index

Tags: imakeidx, makeindex

How can we ignore hyphens when sorting the index? Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=1]
\begin{document}
Test
\index{firstaid}
\index{first-love}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

This code results in:
[image: first-love comes before firstaid]

But we would like "firstaid" to come before "first-love". We could use the `@` option within each instance of `\index`, but I was wondering if there is a global way to set this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get rid of *all* hyphens for sorting, you can do like this, which essentially does automatically `\index{firstlove@first-love}` when the input is `\Index{first-love}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\Index}{om}
 {
  \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str { #2 }
  \str_if_in:NnTF \l_tmpa_str { - }
   {
    \str_set_eq:NN \l_tmpb_str \l_tmpa_str
    \str_remove_all:Nn \l_tmpb_str { - }
    \use:x
     {
      \exp_not:N \index
      \IfValueT { #1 } { [ #1 ] }
      { \str_use:N \l_tmpb_str @ \str_use:N \l_tmpa_str }
     }
   }
   {
    \use:x
     {
      \exp_not:N \index
      \IfValueT { #1 } { [ #1 ] }
      { \str_use:N \l_tmpa_str }
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeindex[columns=1]

\begin{document}

Test
\Index{firstaid}
\Index{first-love}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to keep `\index`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\originalindex\index
  \let\index\newindex
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newindex}{om}
 {
  \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str { #2 }
  \str_if_in:NnTF \l_tmpa_str { - }
   {
    \str_set_eq:NN \l_tmpb_str \l_tmpa_str
    \str_remove_all:Nn \l_tmpb_str { - }
    \use:x
     {
      \exp_not:N \originalindex
      \IfValueT { #1 } { [ #1 ] }
      { \str_use:N \l_tmpb_str @ \str_use:N \l_tmpa_str }
     }
   }
   {
    \use:x
     {
      \exp_not:N \originalindex
      \IfValueT { #1 } { [ #1 ] }
      { \str_use:N \l_tmpa_str }
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeindex[columns=1]

\begin{document}

Test
\index{firstaid}
\index{first-love}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, this is awesome. Is there a way to do it so that I don't have to change `\index` to `\Index` in all of my files?

Comment: @ipswitch Added.

Comment: Great! For those trying to get this to work on their machine, it requires a fairly recent version of the xparse package.